# How to update image styles with JavaScript while making image editor?

Tags: javascript, html, css

While making an image editor I made 9 input ranges for all the 9 filter styles in CSS. In JavaScript I was able to give all those input ranges an event listener so that whenever a range was changed then a function gets executed. Now all that works fine and when you do a

> console.log(inputRanges);

The value gets updated successfully but the problem is that I am not able to update the image styles with JavaScript. I have tried:

> image.style.filter = settings

> image.style.filter = // concatination of settings

none of them are working and I really don't know why.
You can have a look at my code here:

```js
const inputRanges = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]');

inputRanges.forEach((inputRange) => {
    inputRange.addEventListener("change", () => {
        console.log(inputRanges);
      let blur = document.getElementById("blur").value;
      let brightness = document.getElementById("brightness").value;
      let contrast = document.getElementById("contrast").value;
      let saturation = document.getElementById("saturation").value;
      let grayscale = document.getElementById("grayscale").value;
      let hue = document.getElementById("hue").value;
      let opacity = document.getElementById("opacity").value;
      let invert = document.getElementById("invert").value;
        let sepia = document.getElementById("sepia").value;
        
        let settings;

        const image = document.getElementById('previewImage');

        settings = "blur(" + blur + "px) brightness(" + brightness + "%) contrast(" + contrast + "%) saturation(" + saturation + "%) grayscale(" + grayscale + "%) hue(" + hue + "deg) opacity(" + opacity + "%) invert(" + invert + "%) sepia(" + sepia / 100 + "%)";

        image.style.filter = settings;
   });
});
```

```css
body{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 20px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: poppins;
}

img {
   display: block;
   width: 400px;
   height: 266.5px;
   border: 10px solid black;
}

#image{
   overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   background: #383838;
   align-items: center;
   width: fit-content;
   border-radius: 20px;
   padding: 30px;
}

input[type="range"]{
   display: block;
   width: 300px
}

#setting{
   height: 50px;
   width: 400px;
   border-radius: 25px;
   background-color: white;
   margin: 10px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Image Editor</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id='container'>
      <div id="image">
         <img id="previewImage" src="toy car.jpg" alt="Toy Car">
      </div>
      <div id="settings">

         <div id="setting">
            Blur:
            <input type="range" id="blur" min='0' max='20' value="0">
         </div>

         <div id="setting">
            Brightness:
            <input type="range" id="brightness" min='0' max='200' value="100">
         </div>

         <div id="setting">
            Contrast:
            <input type="range" id="contrast" min='0' max='500' value='100'>
         </div>

         <div id="setting">
            Saturation:
            <input type="range" id="saturation" min='0' max='500' value='100'>
         </div>

         <div id="setting">
            Grayscale:
            <input type="range" id="grayscale" min='0' max='100' value='0'>
         </div>

         <div id="setting">
            Hue:
            <input type="range" id="hue" min='0' max='360' value='0'>
         </div>

         <div id="setting">
            Invert:
            <input type="range" id="invert" min='0' max='100'>
         </div>

         <div id="setting">
            Opacity:
            <input type="range" id="opacity" min='0' max='100' value="100">
         </div>

         <div id="setting">
            Sepia:
            <input type="range" id="sepia" min='0' max='100' value="0">
         </div>

      </div>

   </div>

   <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't think you will be able to see the image like this the image link is here:
https://images.pexels.com/photos/386010/pexels-photo-386010.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two filters named wrong, change `hue` to `hue-rotate` and `saturation` to `saturate`. Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp

Comment: Oh no! Didn't notice that while in the flow. Thank you so much I can't believe I didn't notice such a small thing!

Comment: @DragonSoup I'm glad it helped. Don't forget to mark the accepted answer as it can help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Replace settings with

```
settings = `blur(${blur}px) brightness(${brightness}%) contrast(${contrast}%) saturate(${saturation}%) grayscale(${grayscale}%) hue-rotate(${hue}deg) opacity(${opacity}%) invert(${invert}%) sepia(${sepia}%)`;
```

Comment: Yes using template literals should have been better thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

This [Codepen](https://codepen.io/stoumann/pen/MWeNmyb) is similar; worth a look.

```js
/* The main module for this is external. */
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-js="filter"]');
if (elements.length) {
  import('https://elements.stoumann.dk/assets/js/css-filter.mjs')
    .then(module => {
    const jsClass = module.default;
    elements.forEach(element => {
      new jsClass(element, element.dataset, presets);
    });
  })
}

/* Default presets for localhost demo / or when REST API fails */
const presets = [
  {
    "name": "watercolor",
    "description": "",
    "value": "url('#squiggly-1') brightness(1.3) invert(0.17) saturate(2.6) sepia(0.25)",
    "values": [
        {
            "brightness": 1.3,
            "invert": 0.17,
            "saturate": 2.6,
            "sepia": 0.25,
            "url": "url('#squiggly-1')"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "faded-photo",
    "description": "",
    "value": "blur(0.2px) brightness(1.1) hue-rotate(5deg) opacity(0.9) saturate(1.3) sepia(0.4)",
    "values": [
        {
            "blur": 0.2,
            "brightness": 1.1,
            "hue-rotate": 5,
            "opacity": 0.9,
            "saturate": 1.3,
            "sepia": 0.40
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "old-horror",
    "description": "",
    "value": "url('#grain') grayscale(1) sepia(0.5) brightness(1.3) invert(0.8)",
    "values": [
        {
            "url": "url('#grain')",
            "grayscale": 1,
            "sepia": 0.5,
            "brightness": 1.3,
            "invert": 0.8
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "old-grainy",
    "description": "",
    "value": "url('#grain') grayscale(0.6) sepia(0.5) brightness(1.5)",
    "values": [
        {
            "url": "url('#grain')",
            "grayscale": 0.6,
            "sepia": 0.5,
            "brightness": 1.5
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "fade-out",
    "description": "",
    "value": "brightness(0.8) hue-rotate(350deg) saturate(3) blur(8px) contrast(0.6)",
    "values": [
        {
            "brightness": 0.8,
            "hue-rotate": 350,
            "saturate": 3,
            "blur": 8,
            "contrast": 0.6
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "mist",
    "description": "",
    "value": "url('#fluffy') brightness(0.8) saturate(0.8)",
    "values": [
        {
            "url": "url('#fluffy')",
            "brightness": 0.8,
            "saturate": 0.8
        }
    ]
}
];
```

```html
<div data-js="filter"
data-filter-file="#svgfilters"
data-lbl-app-header="CSS &lt;code&gt;filter&lt;/code&gt; Editor"
data-preview-image="https://elements.stoumann.dk/assets/img/filter01.jpg,https://elements.stoumann.dk/assets/img/filter02.jpg,https://elements.stoumann.dk/assets/img/filter03.jpg,https://elements.stoumann.dk/assets/img/filter04.jpg,https://elements.stoumann.dk/assets/img/filter05.jpg">
</div>

<svg id="svgfilters" aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs>
            <filter id="teal-white" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.03 1"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.57 1"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.49 1"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="teal-lightgreen" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.03 0.8"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.57 1"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.49 0.53"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="sepia" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.26 0.95"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.19 0.78"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.11 0.59"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="purple-sepia" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.43 0.97"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.06 0.88"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.37 0.79"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="cherry-icecream" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.84 1"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.05 0.94"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.37 0.61"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="blackCurrant-and-mint" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.75 0.53"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.25 0.97"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.64 0.77"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="sea" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.02 0.13 0.8"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.02 0.47 0.97"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.26 0.52 0.48"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="warm-sea" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.29 0.01 0.97"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.12 0.52 0.94"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.37 0.59 0.47"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="spring-grass" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 0.38 0.92"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.5 0.8 1"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.5 0.56 0.74"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="red-sunset-with-purple" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.52 0.86 0.97"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0.08 0.81"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.51 0.24 0.05"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="red-sunset" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.27 0.86 0.97"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.01 0.08 0.81"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.02 0.24 0.05"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="gold-sunset" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.27 0.86 1"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.01 0.31 0.95"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.02 0.02 0.02"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="dark-crimson-sepia" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.01 0.52 0.97"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0.05 0.81"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.02 0.29 0.61"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="dark-blue-sepia" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.29 0.15 0.97"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.04 0.39 0.93"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.32 0.52 0.73"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="dark-green-sepia" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.25 0.39 0.96"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.16 0.52 0.97"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.06 0.39 0.78"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="x-rays" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.98 0.3 0.25"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="1 0.44 0.24"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.91 0.62 0.39"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="warm-x-rays" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.98 0.75 0.51"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="1 0.45 0.11"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.91 0.39 0.29"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="golden-x-rays" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.98 1 0.94"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="1 0.98 0.44"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.91 0.43 0.02"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="purple-warm" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.52 0.97 1"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0.62 1"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.51 0.39 0.89"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="green-pink-acid" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="1 0.98 0.1"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.17 1 0.82"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.7 0.84 0.67"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="yellow-blue-acid" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    .33 .33 .33 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0" in="SourceGraphic" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComponentTransfer in="colormatrix" result="componentTransfer">
                    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.01 0.97 0.89"/>
                    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.38 1 1"/>
                    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="1 0.89 0.01"/>
                    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feBlend mode="normal" in="componentTransfer" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="noise" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
                <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.01 0.4" result="NOISE" numOctaves="2" />
                <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="NOISE" scale="20" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="R"></feDisplacementMap>
            </filter>
            <filter id="squiggly-0">
                <feTurbulence id="turbulence1" baseFrequency="0.02" numOctaves="3" result="noise" seed="0" />
                <feDisplacementMap id="displacement" in="SourceGraphic" in2="noise" scale="6" />
            </filter>
            <filter id="squiggly-1">
                <feTurbulence id="turbulence2" baseFrequency="0.02" numOctaves="3" result="noise" seed="1" />
                <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="noise" scale="8" />
            </filter>
            <filter id="squiggly-2">
                <feTurbulence id="turbulence3" baseFrequency="0.02" numOctaves="3" result="noise" seed="2" />
                <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="noise" scale="6" />
            </filter>
            <filter id="squiggly-3">
                <feTurbulence id="turbulence4" baseFrequency="0.02" numOctaves="3" result="noise" seed="3" />
                <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="noise" scale="8" />
            </filter>
            <filter id="squiggly-4">
                <feTurbulence id="turbulence5" baseFrequency="0.02" numOctaves="3" result="noise" seed="4" />
                <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="noise" scale="6" />
            </filter>
            <filter id="posterize">
                <feComponentTransfer>
                    <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0 .5 1" />
                </feComponentTransfer>
            </filter>
            <filter id="dancing" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="linearRGB">
                <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="4 4" in="SourceAlpha" result="morphology"/>
                <feFlood flood-color="#30597E" flood-opacity="1" result="flood"/>
                <feComposite in="flood" in2="morphology" operator="in" result="composite"/>
                <feComposite in="composite" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out" result="composite1"/>
                <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.01 0.02" numOctaves="1" seed="0" stitchTiles="stitch" result="turbulence"/>
                <feDisplacementMap in="composite1" in2="turbulence" scale="17" xChannelSelector="A" yChannelSelector="A" result="displacementMap"/>
                <feMerge result="merge">
                    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
                    <feMergeNode in="displacementMap"/>
                    </feMerge>
            </filter>
            <filter id="drops" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.05 0.05" numOctaves="1" seed="3" stitchTiles="stitch" result="turbulence"/>
                <feComposite in="turbulence" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" result="composite"/>
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0
                    0 1 0 0 0
                    0 0 1 0 0
                    0 0 0 25 -2" in="composite" result="colormatrix"/>
                <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="colormatrix" operator="in" result="composite1"/>
                <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3 3" in="composite1" result="blur"/>
                <feSpecularLighting surfaceScale="2" specularConstant="1" specularExponent="20" lighting-color="#fffffd" in="blur" result="specularLighting">
                    <feDistantLight azimuth="-90" elevation="150"/>
                </feSpecularLighting>
                <feSpecularLighting surfaceScale="2" specularConstant="1" specularExponent="20" lighting-color="#cae1fe" in="blur" result="specularLighting1">
                    <feDistantLight azimuth="90" elevation="150"/>
                </feSpecularLighting>
                <feSpecularLighting surfaceScale="7" specularConstant="1" specularExponent="35" lighting-color="#fcfeff" in="blur" result="specularLighting2">
                    <fePointLight x="150" y="50" z="300"/>
                </feSpecularLighting>
                <feComposite in="specularLighting" in2="composite1" operator="in" result="composite2"/>
                <feComposite in="specularLighting2" in2="composite1" operator="in" result="composite3"/>
                <feComposite in="specularLighting1" in2="composite1" operator="in" result="composite4"/>
                <feBlend mode="multiply" in="composite4" in2="SourceGraphic" result="blend"/>
                <feBlend in="composite2" in2="blend" result="blend1"/>
                <feBlend in="composite3" in2="blend1" result="blend2"/>
            </filter>
            <filter id="grain">
                <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.60,0.90" result="colorNoise" />
                <feColorMatrix in="colorNoise" type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0 .33 .33 .33 0 0 .33 .33 .33 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"/>
                <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" result="monoNoise"/>
                <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="monoNoise" mode="multiply" />
            </filter>
            <filter id="fluffy" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
                 <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.04" result="fluffyNoise" numOctaves="5" />
                <feColorMatrix in="fluffyNoise" type="matrix" values=".33 .33 .33 0 0 .33 .33 .33 0 0 .33 .33 .33 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"/>
                <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" result="monoFluffyNoise"/>
                <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="monoFluffyNoise" mode="screen" />
            </filter>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```